Removing an object from a LinkedList vs element using .remove() method
LinkedList arr = new LinkedList<>();
arr.add(2);
arr.add("Anam");
arr.add(1);
System.out.println(arr);
arr.remove(2);
arr.remove("Anam");
System.out.println(arr);

This is a LinkedList of 3 elements of mixed data types (int and String).
I want to use .remove() method to remove using an object name not index.
How do I remove element 2 (at index 1) without using the index, but using the object (element) name via .remove(object) method?
I am using IntelliJ and after many trials, I cannot perform this.
P.S: Every time I try to use .remove(object), it automatically infers an index value. How to use .remove to remove an integer value, by using Integer object as .remove() method argument? I don't want to use index in .remove().

What do you mean you can not? What is the actual issue or error, what is the result?

If you're asking how to cast I'd guess something like .remove( (Object) 2); or .remove( (Object) new Integer(2) ); would work.  But I didn't test it.

Thanks @markspace     .remove( (Object) 2);    or   .remove( (Object) new Integer(2) ); works ! Thanks a lot

You can cast the argument to Object as markspace says above. By the way, it's much better to use ArrayList than LinkedList, at least 99% of the time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/323889/13963086

this was certainly asked before... Properly removing an Integer from a List -- apparently you completed the [tour]: "Don't ask about... * Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for ..."

"elements of mixed data types" well, that's a bad idea right there...

This will remove all of a particular value (you didn't specify what to do if you had multiple of the same value). So do list.removeAll(a->a.equals(2));

Lists in java have the methods remove(Object o) and remove(int index). When you use .remove(2), the 2 is recognized as a primitive int. To use the Object Integer, you need to pass the parameter like this:
    arr.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));

or like this:
    arr.remove((Object) 2);

This casts the primitive int into the object Integer, which then calls remove(Object o) instead of remove(int index).

Did you test this?  That's an honest question, I was concerned that an Integer would be unboxed to an int (and the wrong method called) but I didn't try it.

@markspace The rules say: If the code makes sense as written without needing any boxing, then it is done as written. Only if the code would be an error if boxing/unboxing isn't applied, will java unbox/box. For 'proof', just think about it: if it did not work that way, then the introduction of boxing/unboxing would have been backwards incompatible. What would call the object version of remove before java 1.5, would call the index based one after. A pernicious update; code continues to compile, but does something completely different. Possible, but, idiotic, and, therefore unlikely.

I was worried for the same reason, that's why I tested it and it worked. :) I fully understand your skepticism :)

By the way, (Object) 2 (or (Integer) 2) gets compiled to the same bytecode as Integer.valueOf(2) and takes fewer keystrokes.

YEAH! all the three methods works as I have tested them.
// arr.remove( (Object) 2);
// arr.remove(Integer.valueOf(2));
//  arr.remove( (Object) new Integer(2) );
thanks coding community!
